# When is power and bandwidth shared among USB ports?

Tags: usb, bandwidth

I’d like to know when power and bandwidth is shared among USB ports on a PC.

Let me give an example and please correct me where I may be wrong:

I have a PC with 5 USB ports: three are USB 3.0 and two are USB 2.0.

My understanding is that:

If you plug two USB Hard Drives to two of the USB 3.0 ports:

If they’re plugged to USB 3.0 ports on the same internal Root Hub, they’ll share power and bandwidth.

If they’re plugged to USB 3.0 ports on different internal Root Hubs, they will each get the full speed and power.

If one is plugged to a USB 3.0 port and the other to a USB 2.0 port, they won’t share the power and speed, as USB 3 ports and USB ports always hook to different root hubs, although the USB 2 port will deliver less power and speed.

…if this is true, then I should check device manager to learn which ports are hooked to which Root Hubs.

Any clarification much appreciated

Comment: i am also wondering about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the specifications ([at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power))

Each USB 2.0 EXTERNAL port is supposed to provide upto 500 mA of current.
Each USB 3.0 EXTERNAL port is supposed to provide upto 900 mA of current.

> If they’re plugged to USB 3.0 ports on the same internal Root Hub, they’ll share power and bandwidth.

Even if the are connected to USB3 ports on the SAME internal Root Hubs, each port should have 900 mA of current available separately.

Whether or not they will share bandwidth, will depend on the internal architecture of the system.

There is a discussion here:

[More than 5Gbps bandwidth reported from a USB3.0 / USB3.1 Gen 1 Root Hub, how is it possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/1249361/more-than-5gbps-bandwidth-reported-from-a-usb3-0-usb3-1-gen-1-root-hub-how-is)

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/403090/how-to-determine-bandwidth-available-at-usb-ports

Comment: Great answer.  Super thanks!